# Rising Recursion Relationships

Tags: function-construction, recursion

Lets say I want to compute the following function in mathematica:

$G[n,k]=G[n+1,k-1] + G[n+2,k-2]$ where I know that $G[n,0]=n$ and $G[n,1]=n^2$.

So, for example, $G[3,2]=G[4,1]+G[5,0]=4^2+5$ or, less trivially,

$G[5,4]=G[6,3]+G[7,2]=(G[7,2]+G[8,1])+(G[8,1]+G[9,0])=((G[8,1]+G[9,0])+G[8,1])+(G[8,1]+G[9,0])= 3G[8,1]+2G[9,0]$

So I attempt it with the following code

```
RecurrenceTable[{s1[n, k] == s1[n + 1, k - 1] - s1[n + 2, k - 2], 
   s1[r, 1] == r, s1[r, 0] == r^2}, s1, {n, 2, 6}, {k, 2, 4}] // Grid
```

However it spits out lots of error messages relating to functions being called with two variables when only one is expected.

Comment: It is defined via that recursion relationship with those initial conditions? It is the equivalent of $G[n,k]$ in the example.

Comment: Your sample code doesn't *spit out* any error message here. It just doesn't evaluate to anything. Have you tried restarting the kernel?

Comment: I did, I should mention I am using Mathematica 7, perhaps later editions are smarter...

Comment: Unfortunately, I have only 8.0.4 as *oldest* version here and I cannot test it in 7. In version 8 are no error messages too. Is it seems, `RSolve` and `RecurrenceTable` cannot help you with your problem anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always define the recursive function yourself and use *memoizing* to speed up computation:

```
g[n_, 0] := g[n, 0] = n;
g[n_, 1] := g[n, 1] = n^2;
g[n_, k_] := g[n, k] = g[n + 1, k - 1] + g[n + 2, k - 2];

Table[g[n, k], {k, 0, 10}, {n, 0, 10}] // TableForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Note, this can be solved in general form. Start as

```
RSolve[{G[n, k] == G[n + 1, k - 1] + G[n + 2, k - 2]}, G[n, k], {n, k}]
```

[image]

You have two unknown functions C(1)[x] and C(2)[x] that you can find using your boundary conditions.

Apply your initial conditions G[n,0]:

```
A[n_] = C[1][n] /. 
  Solve[n == (-(1/2) - Sqrt[5]/2)^n C[1][n] + (-(1/2) + Sqrt[5]/2)^
       n C[2][n], C[1][n]][[1]]
```

Apply your initial conditions G[n,1]:

```
B[n_] = C[1][1 + n] /. 
  Solve[n^2 == (-(1/2) - Sqrt[5]/2)^
       n C[1][n + 1] + (-(1/2) + Sqrt[5]/2)^n C[2][n + 1], 
    C[1][n + 1]][[1]]
```

Combine the two above to find function C(2)[n] - I rename it S2[n]:

```
S2[n_] = C[2][1 + n] /. Solve[A[n + 1] == B[n], C[2][1 + n]][[1]] /. 
   n -> n - 1 // FullSimplify
```

Substitute this in A[n] to find C(1)[n] - I rename it S1[n]

```
S1[n_] = (-(1/2) - Sqrt[5]/2)^-n (n - (-(1/2) + Sqrt[5]/2)^n S2[n]) //FullSimplify
```

Finally substitute both in the very original solution to find the final function:

```
SolvedG[n_, k_] = (-(1/2) - Sqrt[5]/2)^n S1[k + n] + (-(1/2) + Sqrt[5]/2)^
    n S2[k + n] // FullSimplify;
```

So here - you got it - the beauty of math:

```
SolvedG[n, k] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Now verify against @halirutan table - identical !

```
Table[SolvedG[n, k] // FullSimplify, {k, 0, 10}, {n, 0, 10}] // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Why does `RSolve` have problems when you specify the initial conditions?

Comment: Interesting! I will say though that the actual recursion relation is much more complicated and I know cannot be solved general form (if I could I would totally be flying to Sweden right now to receive my Nobel Prize...)

Comment: No, this is just a simplified version, my actual problem is non-linear in terms of $n$ and $k$.